# How to run Java application in confined SELinux domain?

Tags: java, selinux

I am working with a Java app that has been labeled with its own SELinux type. Java executes it as `unconfined_t` instead of the labeled type.

Java is labeled as `bin_t` (`ls -Z /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java`)

However `ps -efZ | grep java`  shows it running as `unconfined_t`.

How can I get java to run as `bin_t`? How can I get the java app to runwith the correct context?

The goal is to have the application run in it's own context or at least as `bin_t` as it is launched by Java.

Distribution is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

`bin_t` is a file type, not a process domain. A process enters confined domain via *entry point*, which often is an executable labeled with an entry point file type, for example `httpd_exec_t` for httpd daemon.

Entry points are defined in the policy. If you have policy which defines a process domain, it likely also defines the entry point. Label the executable (script etc) you use to start your application with correct entry point label.